# Difference between Obout Free and paid verison

Tags: asp.net, obout

I'm quite a newbie to asp.net !! . can any one tell me what's the exact difference between obout  paid and free  suite . I mean are there any extra features the provide if i buy  it or is it the same as the free version with just support added to it...... 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I took a look at the Obout website. There isn't a free version of Obout listed on their website.  What you can download otherwise is simply a trial.

Comment: I recently inquired and found the trial versions provided by obout.com lasts for a period of 90 days only from the time of download.... After that all the controls stop working and the whole suite needs to be purchased.....Which simply means as per their tall claims of it being free it just isn't....

Answer (score 2):

Obout has remove expiration from the free version. they have implemented some limitation at some controls. for example, Grid can handle only 100 records at the free version.

for more: 
http://www.obout.com/inc/ultimate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I recently inquired and found the trial versions provided by obout.com lasts for a period of 90 days only from the time of download.... After that all the controls stop working and the whole suite needs to be purchased.....Which simply means as per their tall claims of it being free it just isn't....

Comment: Denzil, they made their standard suite 100% free and non-expiring from jan 2013 only, so I think the expired ones would have got downloaded before jan 2013. I use obout tools and they are so nice and easy

Comment: I downloaded the Standard Suite just now, which is supposed to be free and I got a message that "Evaluation has expired"... I thought it was supposed to be free? Anyone else used the Standard Suite?